# Change property of superclass from subclass

Tags: matlab, class, oop, inheritance

I think this is a very basic question, but I am stuck at this. In MATLAB I have a superclass `super` and subclass `sub`.

Now I am trying to change the property `color` of the superclass from my subclass. So I did the following:

```
classdef super < handle

   properties
       color = 'red';
   end

   methods
      function obj = super()
          % ...
      end

      function obj = change_color( obj )
          obj.color = 'blue';
      end
   end
end
```

And this:

```
classdef sub < super

   properties
       name = 'car';
   end

   methods
      function obj = sub()
          obj = obj@super();
          obj.change_color();
      end
   end
end
```

Next I did:

```
super_obj = super();
sub_obj = sub();
```

But the result is, that I do not change the property of the superclass, but instead the inherited property in the subclass gets changed. I get:

```
super_obj.color = 'red';
sub_obj.color = 'blue';
```

But I want:

```
super_obj.color = 'blue';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only change the `color` property of the *current instance*. If you create two `sub` instances they will have independent colors.

Comment: But doesn´t there exist any possibility to change the property of the superclass from within an inherited subclass?

Comment: No. The inheritance only goes one direction for good reason. What if you had two subclasses that wanted to change color to two different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible since inheritance flows in one direction: from the super class down to the subclass. This is for a very good reason, because what do you think would happen if you had two subclasses which both tried to modify the `color` property of the superclass to two different things?

Furthermore, if you have two instances of the subclass, changing the `color` property in one is not going to change the color property in the other since each instance is de-coupled from the other.

```
sub1 = sub();
sub2 = sub();

sub1.change_color();

sub1.color
%   'blue'

sub2.color
%   'red'
```

If you want all instances to be linked like this, then you likely want them to be references to the *same instance* and you should use the [singleton design pattern](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/controlling-the-number-of-instances.html#buuu4r2) to accomplish this. Even then, though, this only works for objects of the same class and does not affect the superclass.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation.